# how to rename label X in a merged/joined data-frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

When I am trying to merge the two df using:

```
merged = pd.merge(left=df1, left_index=True,
                  right=df2, right_index=True,
                  how='inner')
```

it results in a merged df with headers X and Y based on the df1/df2 which is as expected.

for further/future ease of read, how can i set the label X to be something else?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the `suffixes` parameter to `merge`, which is `('_x','_y')` by default.

Comment: thanks. that was it. got lost in all this documentations....

Answer (score 2):

```
merged = pd.merge(left=df1, left_index=True,
                  right=df2, right_index=True,
                  how='outer',
                  suffixes=('_df_1', '_df_2'))
```